# module.js 340 error Cannot find module 'bonescript'

Tags: debian, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

I am getting this error when trying to use 'bonescript'. I have gone through the many solutions discussed on this forum related to this problem but unfortunately I am not getting. 
I am using Debian OS

The code which I want to run

```js
var b = require('bonescript');
 
b.pinMode('P8_12', b.INPUT);
b.pinMode('P8_13', b.OUTPUT);
 
setInterval(copyInputToOutput, 100);
 
function copyInputToOutput() {
    b.digitalRead('P8_12', writeToOutput);
    function writeToOutput(x) {
        b.digitalWrite('P8_13', x.value);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'bonescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/blinky.js:1:71)
    etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do `npm install bonescript` in the project folder? It can't find that module most likely because it's not installed, or if it is installed it may not have the correct permissions for your app to load it.

Comment: Thanx for your quick reply. I have tried but 'npm install bonescript' is not working. I have also tried 'apt-get install bonescript' but it is also not working.

Comment: what happens when you run 'npm install bonescript'? It's in the npm repsitory (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bonescript)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently,

I was working through Putty and couldn't run program in home directory,
still being able to execute the same program throughout Cloud9 IDE page.

(Working as *root* to be clear)

For me putting these two commands helped:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
export NODE_MODULES_CONTEXTS=1
```

Since then, I was able to run my program and also check *bonescript* version:

```
node -pe "require('bonescript').getPlatform().bonescript"
```